# Redirect after devise sign up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In my sign up form I have a virtual bool parameter :register_as_company (checkbox).

I want users who checked the box to be redirected to 'companies/new' and everyone else to index.

This page has a solution [https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-%28registration%29) but I don't know how to pass my parameter to that method so I can check if the user checked the box or not.

Is there a way to do this? Where should I start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `RegistrationsController`

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    if params[:user][:register_as_company]
        new_company_path
    else
        stored_location_for(resource) || root_path
    end
end
```